# How do I prevent a page from reloading after a video is inserted in a rich text editor?

Tags: jquery, page-refresh, froala

I am using Froala editor, and it worked fine until I migrated to their second version. Every time I insert a youtube or any kind of video using their video plugin the entire page reloads, and then everything is lost. I was wondering if there is a way to prevent a page reload.

Answer (score 0):

It was a well documented froala bug, and they fixed in their latest release.